# Python Nested Loops, If statement, and Function

Tags: python, function, if-statement, nested-loops

I am tasked with using nested loops, an if statement, and a function to reproduce the following table precisely using Python. The X's must be consistent to the example. I am struggling immensely with using functions and other code. I understand that this 9x9 grid has x's in the range 3y-9y, and 4x-9x save for the 9, 9 grid.

My current code is:

```
for x in range (1, 10): for y in range (1, 10):
        print ( ' {:3}' . format(x * y), end = ' ')
    print()
```

Which produces the 9x9 grid. I do not understand how to add a function into this code to create the X's where appropriate.

[Table requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGRs0.png)

Comment: _I do not understand how to add a function into this code_ Do you literally mean you don't know how to create a function?  Or do you mean you're not sure what the function would do?

Comment: I am confused about how to add a function specifically to this code. I guess, logically I do not see the need for a function as the end goal is accomplishable without need for any function - nor does it feel a function makes this any simpler a task.

Answer (score 0):

The guidance "use a function" is pretty vague.

If I were writing this code, I would break it down like this.

Each time through the loop, you're going to print *something*, either a number or the letter x.  So it makes sense (to me at least) to write a function that takes the two arguments x and y, decides what should be printed, and returns the value.

Then your main loop doesn't have to worry about *what* to print; it just calls that function over and over and prints whatever it said.

```
def what_should_i_print(x, y):
    # this function will use if/else to decide
    # whether to return 'x' or return x*y

for x in range (1, 10):
    for y in range (1, 10):
        thing = what_should_i_print(x, y)
        print ( ' {:3}' . format(thing), end = ' ')
    print()
```